# VBA web-scraping: click on element of a list

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I would like to write a vba Programm which downloads automaticaly historical stock data from a web-page.
The correspindent HTML-Code of the Element I would like to select is on the following Picture:
[HTML code of the element I would like to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcWtU.jpg)

My VBA-code Looks as follows:

```
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Dim HTMLDoc As mshtml.HTMLDocument
  Dim HTMLCurButton As mshtml.IHTMLElement

  Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

  IE.Visible = True
  IE.FullScreen = False
  IE.Resizable = True
  IE.Navigate "https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/"

  Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Loop

  Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
  Set HTMLCurButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById(":6n")
  HTMLCurButton.Click
```

But unfortunaly the object HTMLCurButton stays empty.

I am very grateful for any help!

Comment: I think it's because the object you need is in an iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very interesting problem. I don't think you can solve this with Internet Explorer. This is because the list is in an iframe which is protected by a [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) i.e. you cannot navigate to the src of the inner document housing your list.

Using selenium basic vba with Chrome it is possible to switch to the appropriate iframe. You then need a couple of test conditions to be met that allow sufficient time for your actions on the page to take effect.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeChanges()
    'VBE > Tools > References > Selenium Type Library
    'Download: https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/tag/v2.0.9.0
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const url = "https://www.dukascopy.com/swiss/english/marketwatch/historical/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get url
        .SwitchToFrame .FindElementByCss("script + iframe")
        t = Timer
        Do
            With .FindElementByCss("[data-instrument='A.US/USD']")
                .Click
                If .Attribute("aria-selected") Then Exit Do
            End With
        Loop While Timer - t < 10
        With .FindElementByCss(".d-wh-vg-v-p > div")
            If Not .Attribute("aria-disabled") Then .Click
        End With
        'other code now presented with accept and then login details
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It does exactly what I want.

Comment: Now I try to change the date with following code: 'With .FindElementByCss("a-b-c.a-ab-v-y-x > div")
            .FindElementByTag("span").innerText = "2017-01-01"
        End With' but it doesn't work.

Comment: Post as a new question explaining error and I will have a look when at computer

Comment: Ok. I just posted a new question called: "VBA web scraping - change date of a calendar" Thanks!