# How to copy text from a web element division having "CALSS" tag plus "Data-Role" tag in the same division

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

[image: Image showing the code in Chrome Browser from one of the websites I am trying to pull data from]

I am trying to copy the text highlighted in Yellow (from the HTML image) using a Selenium VBA code with MS Excel to a string. However, it is crashing and not getting copied. But the same code is working if I were to use it on other websites where the division does not contain "Data-Role" element within a webpage. I tried to make use of all element type like ByName ById ByClass but none of these technique seems to be working. Please note I am using Selenium to access the Chrome browser. I am trying to store the Yellow highlighted text data into a string "Res". Any help or tip is much appreciated. Below is the sample code which I am trying to use.

```
Dim Res As String
```

Dim be As New WebDriver

On Error Resume Next

be.Start "chrome", ""
be.Get "the website from which I am tryig to pull data"

Res = be.FindElementByClass("text--1jzYQ uppercase--tL_HU").Text

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having the website address (if able to test with it), or any error messages, can't tell you why it is crashing. Possibly accessing a dynamic element which is still resolving? Dunno.

However, those classes look dynamic, so in terms of robustness, perhaps try using a combination of more stable looking attribute = value css selectors:

```
be.FindElementByCss("[data-role=status-bar] [data-role=status-text]").text
```

Comment: I tried above but it isn't working. However, what I noticed is that these codes are within an iFracme. Do you think I need to try accessing them differently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54971406/6241235 Switch to the iframe first

Comment: Yes, that worked I switched to iframe using below codes and it worked. Thanks everyone.
be.SwitchToDefaultContent
be.SwitchToFrame (0)